# ASP.NET MVC: handling logic & variables in the _Layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my `_layout.cshtml` page, I've got some elements that need to be hidden on some pages. I know the pages on which we won't display some parts. For a single page, I could just do this:

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() != "LogIn") {
    <div> .... <div>
}
```

But that gets messy and long with multiple pages. Someplace, ideally not in the `_Layout` page, I could build a list of actions, and if the current action is any of them, set a `boolean` variable (`ShowStuff`) to false. Then just do this on `_Layout`:

```
@if (ShowStuff== true) {
    <div> .... <div>
}
```

I'm just not sure where would be the best-practice way to examine that list of actions and set the boolean. Can the `_Layout` page have it's own model and controller like a normal view?

Comment: A layout page is just a partial used as a master template. It can't have a model and it doesn't need a controller.

Comment: Are they global elements in the layout or global elements in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If devs would stop looking for the 'best way' for every problem they have, that would be great. No best way here, just opinionated solutions. Here's mine: You can create an action filter [ShowNav] and decorate any controller/action you need. That filter will put a boolean into HttpContext.Items . Create then a HtmlHelper which checks for the boolean. Then in _layout, `if (Html.CanShowNavig()) { <nav> }` . That's the easiest solution that comes to my mind.

Comment: Ok.  An HTML Helper. I had not thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually an action filter (the most important part) + html helper

Comment: Ok... I'm not familiar with action filters. I'll spend some time on Google

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to MikeSW answer, I'd use an action filter, but I would populate ViewData with a specific ViewModel.  When you want to display it simply DisplayFor the value, if it's populated the template is used by whatever type the model is, if it's null nothing is displayed.  (examples below from memory, may not be exactly correct.)

```
public BlahModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    BlahModel model = Db.GetModel();
    filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Set(model);
  }
}
```

ViewData extensions:

```
public static ViewDataExtensions
{
  private static string GetName<T>()
    : where T : class
  {
    return typeof(T).FullName;
  }

  public static void Set<T>(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, T value)
    : where T : class
  {
    var name = GetName<T>();
    viewData[name] = value;
  }

  public static T Get<T>(this ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    : where T : class
  {
    var name = GetName<T>();
    return viewData[name] as T;
  }
}
```

In your view:

```
@{var blahModel = ViewData.Get<BlahModel>() }
@Html.DisplayFor(m => blahModel)
```